# Splitting Column with Delimiter Appearing more than Once

Tags: python, pandas

I have the following line in my code where I'm taking a string and splitting it based on a delimiter:

```
task_df[['Project','Section']] = task_df.Projects.str.split(": ",expand=True)
#sample Projects = Rob's Project: Untitled Section
```

But I'm running into issues whenever someone adds a Project or Section name that also contains my delimiter ex. `Project X:  Section: Rob`

error:
ValueError: Columns must be same length as key

NOTE: Sometimes the duplicate : will be in the project, but most times it's in the Section Name

How would I account for this in my code? Is there any way to cleanly avoid this from being an error? If not, how can I make it just remove those that would cause the error?

Comment: Can you produce a small dataset that shows this error and post it here?

Comment: I provided two data points: one that is working and one that gives the error

Comment: Maybe pass `n=1` to `Series.str.split()`? That way you split on the first `:` encountered, instead of all of them.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

IIUC, you need only the first and second part, if the same sep exists more than once, they should be joined by the same sep. Therefore:

```
  task_df['Project'] = task_df['Projects'].str.split(": ").str[0]
  task_df['Section'] = task_df['Projects'].str.split(": ").str[1:].map(lambda x: ": ".join(x))
```

For this dataset:

```
                          Projects
0  Rob's Project: Untitled Section
1         Project X:  Section: Rob
```

This is the output:

```
                          Projects        Project           Section
0  Rob's Project: Untitled Section  Rob's Project  Untitled Section
1         Project X:  Section: Rob      Project X      Section: Rob
```